# C# async Task vs Js async Task (node js)

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Ok, so I know how to program in C# fairly well and I have started programming in JS recently (node js). To be honest I was in a bot of shock from async calls.

Let's say I have this code in C#:

```
var t_1 = SomeAsyncTask();
var t_2 = SomeOtherAsyncTask();
Task.WaitAll(t_1, t_2);
var res_1 = t_1.Result;
var res_2 = t_2.Result;
```

Is there a JS equivalent of this? So far I have managed this:

```
In User.js:
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var sqlDo = require("../../js_help/DatabasReq/sqlDo.js");
router.get("/", async function(req, res){
    var json = sqlDo.ExecCommand("select * from Users");
    res.send(json); //json.recordset
});
module.exports = router;

In sqlDo.js:
module.exports = {
    ExecCommand: function(command){
        // sql and config are defined before.
        sql.connect(config, function () {
            var request = new sql.Request();
            request.query(command, function (err, recordset) {
                if (err) console.log(err)
                console.log(recordset.recordset);
                return recordset;
            });
        });
    }
};
```

My problem is that this code is running async. I have tried putting await to different places but nothing worked. So when I start my server it returns nothing. I can tell that it is completing a call because I let it read results into console.

Thanks for any help!

Btw: I have tried googling/stackoverlow-ing,.. But I was not able to find anything that would look like C# equivalent. Is it even possible to write it like in c#? Again thanks for every answer...

Comment: The nearest to `Task.WaitAll(t1, t2)` would be `Promise.all([p1, p2])` as `async/await` in JS is more or less syntactic sugar for promises.

Comment: It wouldn't be too much of an exaggeration to say that *all* "classic" languages (C, C++, Java and C#) are essentially "blocking", and, in contrast, Javascript was *always* "asynchronous".  One wait to achieve an "await" in JS is to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).   "Async" was bolted on to later versions of .Net/C#; "Promises" to later versions of JS.

Comment: Ok, so how can I join to the database and then return responce with data from database. And I want to have it in some function, so I can reuse it?

Comment: Q: Ok, so how can I join to the database...?  A: Look at the link I cited.  Have your callback return a promise; have your caller(s) wait on the promise.  Easy peasy ;)

Comment: To stay within your above example: `ExecCommand` has to be an `async` function (ie returning a promise), and in your requesthandler you have to `await ExecCommand(...)` before returning the result. Basically the same, as you would do it with `Task`s in C#

Comment: A (to derpirscher): I have tried making ExecCommand async and then awaiting it but it does not work. It runs async. A (to paulsm4): Thanks for link! I will look more deeply into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your `ExecCommand` function async, you have to make it return a Promise. Read about Promises for instance [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-promises-explained/)

```
module.exports = {

  ExecCommand: function(command){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  //return a Promise from the function
      sql.connect(config, function () {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query(command, function (err, recordset) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);  //if there is an error, reject the Promise
          } else {
            resolve(recordset);  //if no error, resolve the Promise with the result
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Depending on your SQL library, it may also support promises already, instead of callbacks

```
module.exports = {

  ExecCommand: function(command) {
     return sql.connect(config)
       .then(() => {
          return new sql.Request().query(command);
       })
  }
};
```

or with `async/await`

```
module.exports = {

  ExecCommand: async function(command) {
    await sql.connect(config);
    return await new sql.Request().query(command);         
  }
};
```

Then you can call this function in the requesthandler either like this

```
router.get("/", async function(req, res){
  try {
    var json = await sqlDo.ExecCommand("select * from Users");
    res.send(json); 
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

or like this

```
router.get("/", function(req, res){
  sqlDo.ExecCommand("select * from Users")
    .then(json => { //the promise resolved
      res.send(json);
    })
    .catch(err => { //the promise rejected
      res.sendStatus(500); 
      console.log(err); 
    });
});
```

I prefer the second variant. But that may be just my personal opinion ...

Comment: Wow! Thanks, I actually understood what is going on from your examples. Approve and upvote. Hope you have a grate day